# ContentView label binding Cant find property in viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a label i want to bind to a property in my viewModel. But when running my code, it returns the fallback value, eventhough there is another value. In the output it writes:
Binding: 'Name' property not found on ContentViews.OverviewView', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

Binding: 'Match' property not found on ContentViews.OverviewView', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
My code
XAML

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#37474F">
            <Label Text="{Binding Match.Result.ScoreInfo.Score[1}.Name, FallbackValue=0-0}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Match.Result.ScoreInfo.Score[0].Name, FallbackValue=0-0}" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
```

CodeBehind

```
  public OverviewViewModel OVM { get; set; }

        public OverviewView(Models.Match match)
        {
            OVM = new OverviewViewModel(match);
            BindingContext = OVM;
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
```

ViewModel

```
public Match Match { get; set; }
        public OverviewViewModel(Match match)
        {
            Match = match;
        }
```

If i set the label text in code behind there isnt any issue and the correct result returns. 
What could be the issue?

Comment: there's a typo here: Score[1}.Name

Comment: Thanks! It still returns the fallbackvalue after i corrected it though

Comment: try having a private match variable: private Match _match;
and then in the Getter and Setter of the public one, get and set the private one:
public Match Match { get => _match; set { _match = value; } }

Comment: if your viewmodel implements the INotifyPropertyChanged (wich it should), doing this should invoke the propertychanged method, if not, you can use OnPropertyChanged(); after setting the _match value in the setter

Comment: if none of that works, it might be another Syntax error in the xaml. with the information given, i can't do much more

Comment: Have tried what you suggested. It does Implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Is there anything else i can provide you with? the weird thing is on the same page, as a part of another view. The label can show the correct result binding through the xaml

Comment: What happens if you try to create an string ScoreName, say that the ScoreName = Match.Result.ScoreInfo.Score[1}.Name, and then bind the string to the xaml?

Comment: It gets set in the ViewModel to the correct result, and when i debug and check the the instance of my viewmodel im setting the BindingContext to. It also have the correct result, but it still returns the fallbackvalue when i run it. and this in the debug output: Binding: 'ScoreName' property not found on ContentViews.OverviewView', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

Comment: then i think you are not "giving" xaml the correct ViewModel, where are you making the binding context? are you using any MVVM framework like prism or freshmvvm?

Comment: try this:     <ContentView.BindingContext>
    <viewModels: OverviewViewModel/>
  </ContentView.BindingContext>

Comment: I dont use any framework for this.

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais it appear that the issue might be due to the page being a part af collection for a carouselview for some reason? If I create an instans of the view outside the carouselview the labels are returning the correct result. What could be the issue?

Comment: In that case yes, you are not giving the right context to it, since it "lives" inside de carrousel view, so you need to say that your context source is the carrousell view, give a x:Name = "CarrouselView" to your carrousell controller, then: Text="{Binding BindingContext.Match.Result.ScoreInfo.Score[0].Name, Source={x:Reference Name=CarrouselView}}"

Comment: Does it need to be on the same page? the reference? cause i have set it like this
<CarouselView
                    x:Name="CarouselMatch">                  
                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame>
                                <ContentView x:Name="ContentViewLV" Content="{Binding Content}" />
                            </Frame>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </CarouselView>
            </ContentView>

Comment: And then my ViewModel have the collection of contentviews

 CP = new ObservableCollection<ContentView>
            {                
                new OverviewView(Match),
                new LineUpView(Match),
                new StatsView(Match),
                new Head2HeadView(Match) };              
                    }          
        }

Comment: i think you can do this: Content="{Binding BindingContext.Content, Source={x:Reference Name=CarrouselView}}"

Comment: it did not seem to fix the issue

Comment: The code in the comment is  fragmented, could you please post a basic demo so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the Syntax here.

It should be Score[1].Name:-

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Match.Result.ScoreInfo.Score[1].Name, FallbackValue=0-0}" />
```

Comment: Thanks! However it still returns the fallback value

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the binding context after your call to InitializeComponent.

Comment: still returns the fallback value